# GitHub workflow to trigger another workflow

Tags: github-actions

I have 2 workflow files;

- 1 for changes in `infrastructure` folder
- 1 for all other changes in the rest of the monorepo

`infrastructure` contains AWS CDK code for general project resources. Applications may require some global resources being available before I want to deploy these. So I would like to get these deployed before deploying an application.

Is there a way I can run the `deploy` workflow:

- If there are `infrastructure` changes, run its workflow first, then the `deploy` one after
- If there no `infrastructure` changes run the `deploy` workflow anyway

`needs` seems to reference a `job` within the same workflow

`workflow_run` wants a status of `completed`, `in_progress` or `requested`.

Can this be done or will I need to incorporate `infrastructure` jobs inside the deploy workflow?

```yaml
name: infrastructure

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'infrastructure/**'
      - '**.md'

jobs:
  infrastructure:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
```

```yaml
name: deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths-ignore:
      - 'infrastructure/**'
      - '**.md'
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: 'Environment to deploy'
        type: environment
        required: true
        default: 'dev'
```

Comment: Why not just trigger deploy directly _from_ infrastructure? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_call

Comment: because infrastructure may not run if there are no changes to it

Comment: But that's when you're already triggering deploy directly anyway, that's dealt with.